# Getting Error: "Invalid DateTimeKind-Value. Parametername: kind"

Tags: vb.net, datetime, time

I have the following Code:

```
Dim TimeVon As Date = Booking.From


Dim DateVon As Date = New Date(TimeVon.Minute, TimeVon.Hour)
```

In Booking.From the DateTime is saved as : `2/1/2013 12:30:00`

I try to get the Time with the second line, but that Error appears every Time. What iam doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `New Date(TimeVon.Minute, TimeVon.Hour)` is a valid constructor, see [DateTime Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime.aspx).

`Date` inherently always contains a Date and a Time component. What are you trying to do with the time? You can always display the time like [`DateVon.ToShortTimeString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring.aspx)